# Does global(s).d.ts have a special meaning in typescript?

Tags: typescript

As far as I can tell any script-like `.ts` or `.d.ts` file (as in not a module)  populates global namespace.
Except for the case where `{file}.d.ts` gets shadowed by `{file}.ts`, then the `{file}.d.ts` gets ignored.

Does this mean any `.d.ts` can be used as a global declarations file, and `global.d.ts` or `globals.d.ts` is just a convention?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean any .d.ts can be used as a global declarations file, and global.d.ts or globals.d.ts is just a convention

Yes. Its just a convention. TypeScript itself holds no special meaning for the name `global/globals`